# Is there a way to turn a non convex set to a convex one?

Tags: convexity, convex-analysis, nonnegative-matrices

Perhaps the question is rather vague, but if we are given a non-convex set S, can we construct some invertible mapping f so that f(x) becomes a convex set?

In my problem , I am given a set of matrix that are all nonnegative and have the same nonnegative rank. I suppose this is a non convex set, but i want to come up with a invertible function f so that when do the entrywise mapping on each matrix, we get a convex set of matrix. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Perhaps you left out a negation: "if we are given a ***non***-convex set $S$..."?

Comment: You need to require something about f. "An invertible function" is too general to make this a nontrivial question.

Comment: Perhaps this could help? Bertsekas, D. P. "Convexification procedures and decomposition methods for nonconvex optimization problems." *Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications* 29, no. 2 (1979): 169-197. [PDF download](http://web.mit.edu/dimitrib/www/Convexification_Mult.pdf).

Comment: Assume $S$ has cardinality continuum, then take a bijection to $[0,1]$.  Clearly you mean continuous and invertible? If $S$ is countable and has more than one point then I don't think it can be done :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts but does the bijection guarantee the resulting set of matrices convex?  Just an emphasis, im doing a entrywise map via this invertible function.

Comment: The resulting set is an interval in the real line, I was pointing out how useless a general, non-continuous bijection is. Nik's answer is correct, it cannot be done.

Answer (score 5):

For instance, the set of positive rank 1 $n\times n$ matrices is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ modulo identification of $x$ with $-x$, or $\mathbb{C}^n\setminus \{0\}$ modulo the action of the circle group. For $n>1$ these spaces have nontrivial homology so cannot be homeomorphic to a convex set.

Comment: hi, im not familiar with this homeomorphic topic. can you elaborate more on the impossibility of homeomorphic to a convex set? thanks !

Comment: I suspect you will need to learn a lot more math before this will make sense to you.

Comment: 'the set of positive rank 1 × matrices is homeomorphic to ℝ∖{0} modulo identification of  with −', can I understand this by seeing that any rank 1postive  matrix can be written as the outer product of some vector in  ℝ, so the double continuous bijection map would be a map from matrix in outer product form to that vector? And since we're considering positive matrices,  we modulo out the identification of  with  −. What about rank-1 matrices that is n by m ? Thanks a lot !